# Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero in part of the program where it should divide numbers

Tags: java

I tried searching stackoverflow for answer but i could not find it. i figured out when i remove part of the program that divides numbers:

```
if(znak == 0) {
                Resenje = x + y;    
            }else if(znak == 1) {
                Resenje = x - y;
            }else if(znak == 2) {
                Resenje = x/y;
            } else if(znak == 3) {
                Resenje = x*y;
            }else {
                System.out.println("Greska u programu");
            }
```

that error does not appear. i think the problem maybe if number is float but it is stored in int... Thank you, if you need any additional information im here to provide it.. :) 
PS code is messy because i made it long time ago..  sorry, i cant figure out how to properly format it, i posted it on pastebin, i hope you dont mind it.. :)

https://pastebin.com/sfG9JEbR link for code

```
while(vece = true) {
            //  System.out.println(Odabir1);
                x = random.nextInt(Odabir1);
            //  System.out.println(x);
                y = random.nextInt(Odabir1);
            //  System.out.println(y);
                //if(x == (int)x) {
                if(x-y >= 0 && x+y <= Odabir1 && x+y!=0 && x-y!=0 && x/y >= 0 && x/y == (int)x && x*y >= 0 && x*y <= Odabir1) {
                    System.out.println(x + " " + y);
                    break;
                }

            }
```

when i try adding && y == 0; i get same error in every possibility

Comment: are you dividing by zero?

Comment: i tried adding && y == 0; to this part but then i get same error in every possibility. i will put code in reply

Comment: you need to add the check `y == 0` before the `&& x/y ...` part
which actually doesn't help, you need to check `y != 0` ;)

Comment: Thank you! problem was that program would crash when it would check if dividing was greater than 0, as you said